# css completely remove instead of just visibility:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

This question is pretty straight forward.
I have a button that toggles a div element:

```
var status = false;
$("#tab").click(function () {
    if (status != true) {
        $(".container2").css({ "visibility": "visible" });
        status = true;
    } else {
        $(".container2").removeAttr('style');
        status = false;
    }
});
```

The problem is, that when it's hidden, it takes up "invisible" space, so that the rest of my elements on the page, looks misplaced.

Is there a way I can completely remove my `<div>` element in my DOM, so that it doesn't take up space, like when I do:

```
visibility:hidden
```

In case, how would I use the jQuery .detach() function? I can make it disappear, but I am not able to bring it back again.

Comment: `display: none` would hide and remove it from sizing/positioning calculations. `visibility` is basically just a cloak of invisibility. can't see it, but it's still present for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `remove()` function like following to remove an element from DOM.

```
$(".container2").remove();
```

**Update** If you don't want remove then use `hide()` and `show()` function.

```
$(".container2").hide(); //to hide
$(".container2").show();  //to show
```

Also you can use `toggle()` function toggle visibility.

```
$("#tab").click(function () {
    $(".container2").toggle();
});
```

Comment: how would i then make it reappear?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

JS

```
$("#tab").click(function () {
    $(".container2").toggle();
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to hide it and remove it from the flow (as opposed to outright deletion), `$(".container2").hide();`.

Alternatively, `display:none` via CSS, `$(".container2").css("display:none");` which does the same thing, but is more explicit.

Showing it again you would use `$(".container2").show();` or set the display back to block, `$(".container2").css("display:block");`.

There are other jQuery alternatives to `.hide()` as well, such as `.toggle()` `.fade()` and `.slide()` which will animate the hide/show in addition to removing it from document flow.

http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: `hide()` does not fade it out. `fadeOut()` does. All `hide()` does is add the inline style `display:none;`